# failed to enroll MOK key on upgrade 17.10 -> 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, keyboard-layout, secure-boot

I upgraded my development edition Dell XPS 13 9360 (i.e. single-boot Ubuntu) from 17.10 to 18.04. During installation, I was asked whether I wanted to create a MOK key to install third-party drivers under secure boot. I said yes and specified a password. After restarting, I was met by the MOK management menu, with four options (iirc):

1. `continue boot`
2. `change secure boot state`
3. `enroll key from disk`
4. `enroll hash from disk`

I chose 3.  However, it didn't accept my password, so all I could do was to proceed with 1.

The upgrade completed without issues, but in order to decide for myself whether this is a problem, I want to better understand the situation.

Specifically, I would like to know:

1. Was `enroll key from disk` the correct option?
2. Why was my password rejected? Could it be the MOK management menu uses a different keyboard layout from my standard layout in Ubuntu?
3. Does this mean certain third-party drivers were not installed? How do I know which drivers, and how do I get a 'second chance', so to speak?
4. `mokutil --sb-state` says SecureBoot is enabled, but I seem to get a message saying secure boot is disabled at least sometimes on startup. Perhaps only when I reboot? Is this significant?
5. Do I even need third party drivers on this system? The only components that I feel could work better are the wifi, the touchpad (palm sensitivity when typing) and audio quality with plugged in earphones.

Comment: You can get a second chance. The manual way is to extract `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der` from the upgraded system, and copy it to either the EFI partition or a USB stick. Then start the MOK Manager again, enroll key from disk, and browse to `MOK.der`. You can also use `update-secureboot-policy` or `mokutil` with the appropriate flags to enroll/import keys. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS#Manual_method